# How do I install CEFPython on Mac, Its throwing errors

Tags: python, pip, cefpython

I'm having issues getting cefpython to install on Mac. I know someone who got it to install fine on windows, but on Mac, no dice. I've tried `pip3 install cefpython3==66.0`, but it throws this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cefpython3==66.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cefpython3==66.0
```

I should also note that I haven't had issues installing other packages with pip3. I thought that I might need to use pip instead of pip3, but that currently isn't working either.

Comment: Mac with processor M1, not Intel?

Comment: Yeah, it's the M1

Answer (score 0):

`cefpython3` 66.0 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/cefpython3/66.0/#files) for Linux, w32/w64 and MacOS, but only for Intel processors. Other releases [provide](https://pypi.org/project/cefpython3/66.1/#files) even less. And there is no source code.

To install cefpython3 on MacOS M1 you need to compile from sources. See https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/docs/Build-instructions.md